# What is mm benchmark in RISC V benchmark suite

Tags: riscv

I'm not sure what kind of computation do the mm benchmark in rocketchip architectures. In this link contain the becnhmark mm. https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tests/tree/130702297a010b4a2e7452bb48f0da88c0b30aa9/benchmarks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matrix multiply. Both blocked and unblocked implementations.